# "Всё равно": нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис

Нужна ли запятая после оборота "всё равно"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение «всё равно» может являться как наречием (*Всё равно мне идти ко второй паре*), так и сказуемым в предложении (*А нам всё равно*).

В обоих случаях запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "всё равно" тождественно наречию "безразлично". Не выделяется запятыми.